# SQL Server 2008: BULK INSERT csv - is it possible to choose fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing:

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO

--Drop the table to clean up database.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO
```

Is it possible to insert only specific fields FROM the csv?

Comment: @marc_s: btw mark i just need a way to import a csv

Comment: I had a similar issue. Please check out my blog post, it may help you:
[Import Data from a Text or CSV file into SQL Server](http://willmtz.blogspot.com/2011/10/import-data-from-text-or-csv-file-into.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can [bulk insert into a view](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2008/08/ms-sql-selective-bulk-insert-without.html).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893777/sql-server-2008-is-it-possible-to-specify-format-instead-of-using-formatfile).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a format file. See: [Using a Format File to Skip a Table Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx) and [Using a Format File to Skip a Data Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187908.aspx).

Comment: As always, I don't mind a down vote if I'm wrong, but I do dislike an anonymous down vote with no explanation. Can you explain your objection?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlBulkInsertExample
{
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable prodSalesData = new DataTable("ProductSalesData");

            // Create Column 1: SaleDate
            DataColumn dateColumn = new DataColumn();
            dateColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
            dateColumn.ColumnName = "SaleDate";

            // Create Column 2: ProductName
            DataColumn productNameColumn = new DataColumn();
            productNameColumn.ColumnName = "ProductName";

            // Create Column 3: TotalSales
            DataColumn totalSalesColumn = new DataColumn();
            totalSalesColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            totalSalesColumn.ColumnName = "TotalSales";

            // Add the columns to the ProductSalesData DataTable
            prodSalesData.Columns.Add(dateColumn);
            prodSalesData.Columns.Add(productNameColumn);
            prodSalesData.Columns.Add(totalSalesColumn);

            // Let's populate the datatable with our stats.
            // You can add as many rows as you want here!

            // Create a new row
            DataRow dailyProductSalesRow = prodSalesData.NewRow();
            dailyProductSalesRow["SaleDate"] = DateTime.Now.Date;
            dailyProductSalesRow["ProductName"] = "Nike";
            dailyProductSalesRow["TotalSales"] = 10;

            // Add the row to the ProductSalesData DataTable
            prodSalesData.Rows.Add(dailyProductSalesRow);

            // Copy the DataTable to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ProductHost;Initial Catalog=dbProduct;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=60;Min Pool Size=2;Max Pool Size=20;"))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
                {
                    s.DestinationTableName = prodSalesData.TableName;

                    foreach (var column in prodSalesData.Columns)
                        s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

                    s.WriteToServer(prodSalesData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
The Output is
select * from dbo.ProductSalesData

SaleDate               ProductName  TotalSales
27/08/2013 00:00:00    Nike         10
```