# sql server 2008: is it possible to specify format instead of using formatfile?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
INSERT INTO myTestSkipField 
   SELECT *
      FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\myTestSkipField-c.dat',
      FORMATFILE='C:\myTestSkipField.fmt'  
       ) AS t1;
GO
```

i dont want to specify a `formatfile`!!! i just want to specify the format inline. is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [SQL Server 2008: BULK INSERT csv - is it possible to choose fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893619/sql-server-2008-bulk-insert-csv-is-it-possible-to-choose-fields/3893710#3893710)

Comment: No, this is a different question. He wants to do it without a format file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to specify the format as a parameter to either `OPENROWSET` or `BULK INSERT`.

You can however [insert the data into a view](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2008/08/ms-sql-selective-bulk-insert-without.html). IMO this is an elegant solution.