# sql server: can i insert a $ into a money field

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

i am inserting values like '`$5.99`' (or trying to insert) into a `money` field. it doesnt like the dollars sign

i am actually doing a bulk insert from a csv file. one of the columns in the csv file has `money` in it with a dollar sign

can you please help me figure out how to do this bulk insert with the `$` sign into a `money` field?

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 2 (pricepaid).
```

how do i get rid of the sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this question, as well as your earlier questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893619/sql-server-2008-bulk-insert-csv-is-it-possible-to-choose-fields/3893710#3893710) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893777/sql-server-2008-is-it-possible-to-specify-format-instead-of-using-formatfile), I'd recommend that you do your bulk insert into a temporary holding table, where you could define your "money" field as a varchar. Then write another SQL statement to move the data from the holding table to the real table. In this SQL statement, you could skip unwanted columns, remove the '$' from your "money" field and cast it as a money data type, etc.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't insert currency symbols into a money field.

It's really just a decimal(19,4) with a friendly name.

Comment: so what is the solution fo rme?

Comment: is it possible to format the data before it enter the DB with BULK INSERT?

Comment: Do you need to make this a repeatable process? If not, perhaps just manipulate the CSV in MS Excel beforehand to remove the currency symbol?

Comment: i do need to make it repeatable!

Comment: Then I would go with the temp table option suggested by adrift and Joe Stefanelli.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you could create a table with the same schema as your target, using a varchar column instead of money, and bulk insert into that.  Then update the imported table to remove the '$' and copy the data to the original target.

Answer (score 2):

you can't, Money is just a numeric type slightly less flexible than decimal. to store with the symbol you would have to use a varchar

Comment: is it possible to format the data before it enter the DB with BULK INSERT?

Comment: I would use Joe Stefanelli's suggestion personally

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested a temporary table. If you use a temp table to hold the raw data from your CSV file, you should be able to convert directly to `Money` from a `Varchar` or `Char` field containing a $ character (that is, without removing it).

This worked for me in SQL 2008.

Comment: Somehow, that doesn't surprise me. I assumed that this was a valid answer here because jenny prefaced the other questions with "SQL Server 2008."